# How to find slow queries and fix, is there any tool to find slow queries in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-9.5

```
select
   min(aml.id) as id,
   aml.name as name,
   round(sum(aml.debit),2) as debit,
   round(sum(aml.credit),2) as credit,
   round(sum(aml.balance),2) as balance,                
   aml.account_id as account_id,
   aml.move_id as move_id,
   aml.journal_id as journal_id,
   aml.date as date,
   aml.company_id as company_id,
   aml.invoice_id as invoice_id,
   aml.partner_id as partner_id
 from 
    account_move_line aml
 group by
   aml.name,
   aml.debit,
   aml.credit,
   aml.balance,
   aml.account_id,
   aml.move_id,
   aml.journal_id,
   aml.date,
   aml.company_id,
   aml.invoice_id,
   aml.partner_id
 order by 
   id limit 10
```

How to find slow queries and fix, is there any tool to find slow queries in PostgreSQL?
I am stick with this query it is taking 1 min to load.
/***Explain Shows***/

```
Limit  (cost=120766.57..120766.59 rows=10 width=76)
   ->  Sort  (cost=120766.57..122071.83 rows=522104 width=76)
         Sort Key: (min(id))
         ->  HashAggregate  (cost=96431.49..109484.09 rows=522104 width=76)
               Group Key: name, debit, credit, balance, account_id, move_id, journal_id, date, company_id, invoice_id, partner_id
               ->  Seq Scan on account_move_line aml  (cost=0.00..47130.05 rows=1314705 width=76)
```

/***Explain Analyze Shows***/

```
Limit  (cost=120766.57..120766.59 rows=10 width=76) (actual time=67457.650..67457.657 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=120766.57..122071.83 rows=522104 width=76) (actual time=67457.636..67457.636 rows=10 loops=1)
         Sort Key: (min(id))
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 26kB
         ->  HashAggregate  (cost=96431.49..109484.09 rows=522104 width=76) (actual time=65464.360..67028.469 rows=1314669 loops=1)
               Group Key: name, debit, credit, balance, account_id, move_id, journal_id, date, company_id, invoice_id, partner_id
               ->  Seq Scan on account_move_line aml  (cost=0.00..47130.05 rows=1314705 width=76) (actual time=118.524..51252.823 rows=1314705 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.742 ms
 Execution time: 67610.996 ms
```

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN`, or the equivalent of that in Postgres.

Comment: The title of your question and your actual question have little in common. You should edit your question so that we know what you are asking. Also, you need `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output, and you should edit the question rather than adding it as a comment.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen What is the equivalent of `EXPLAIN` in PostgreSQL?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe edited my question

Answer (score 1):

To find the queries that consume most time, use the `pg_stat_statements` contrib.

About your slow query:

Most of the time is spent reading the table from storage. Now 50 seconds for a million rows sounds pretty excessive and raises a few questions:

- What kind of storage is that?
- Is the table very bloated (what does `pg_relation_size` report)?
- Is the I/O system overloaded (check with `sar`, `iostat` or other operating system tools)?
- Could it be that there is too little RAM in the machine so nothing gets cached in memory?

Apart from that, it *may* be that raising `work_mem` can turn the HashAggregate into a GroupAggregate and save a few seconds.

Comment: right now i am checking in my laptop, which have 4 gb RAM.                                       pg_relation_size is 265 MB and i have an physical server which have 16GB RAM,500GB sas hdd, xeon processor, running in ubuntu 16.04.4

Comment: Table size is ok - a little bit bloated maybe, but not bad. I'd say your I/O system has a problem: 118 ms until the *first* page in a sequential scan is read does not sound right.